# How to mirror local MySQL database to online (realtime) MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm a noob, is there someone could help me with this?

I have a local SQL database using Xampp thru phpMyAdmin and i want to mirror it to online MySQL in my website.

When I'm making changes to my local database, I want my online database to be updated (Realtime) with the changes made.

Is this possible? Can I have a sample php code or whatever that can do this?  Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many times ago I wrote some script for this problem. As said above - replication it's really good solution but in my case I could not use it. So.. if you need some like replication by master->slave maybe this script will be useffull :

```
dumps.sh : 
while getopts "c:l:" opt; do
        case $opt in
                c)
                if [ -r "$OPTARG" ]; then
                                source "$OPTARG"
                        else
                                echo "Unreadable config file \"$OPTARG\""
                                exit 1
                        fi
                        ;;
                l) LOG_FILE="$OPTARG"
                        if [ ! -f "$LOG_FILE" ]; then
                                `touch $LOG_FILE`
                        fi
                        ;;
                \?) echo "Invalid options. -$OPTARG. USE -c config_file"
                        exit 1
                        ;;
                 :) "Option -$OPTARG requires an argument."
                        ;;
        esac
done

logIt()
{
        date_now=`date '+%D %T'`
        if [ $LOG_FILE != "" ]; then
                echo "$date_now : $*" >> $LOG_FILE
        else
                echo "$date_now : $*"
        fi
}

build_tables()
{
        TAB=""
        logIt $@
        for table in $TABLES
        do
                TAB="$TAB ${1}${table}"
        done
        echo $TAB
}
MYSQLDUMP="$(which mysqldump)"
CHOWN="$(which chown)"
CHMOD="$(which chmod)"
GZIP="$(which gzip)"
RM="$(which rm)"
DEST="."

MBD="$DEST/mysql"
eval $RM -fv "$MBD/*"
FILE=""

[ ! -d $MBD ] && mkdir -p $MBD || :

$CHOWN 0.0 -R $DEST
$CHMOD 0600 $DEST

TAB=`build_tables $DB_PREFIX`

FILE="$MBD/$DB_NAME.sql";
($MYSQLDUMP -u $MyUSER -h $MyHOST -p$MyPASS $DB_NAME $TAB  2>> $LOG_FILE) > $FILE


input_to_mysql()
{
        ###############################3
        CP="$(which cp)"
        SED="$(which sed)"
        len=${#INSERT_DB_NAME[*]}
        i=0

        while [ $i -lt $len ]; do
                NEW_FILE="$MBD/${INSERT_DB_NAME[$i]}.sql"
                eval $CP $FILE $NEW_FILE
                eval $SED -i "s/$DB_PREFIX/${INSERT_DB_PREFIX[$i]}/g" $NEW_FILE
                eval $SED -i "s/^.\*!.*$//g" $NEW_FILE
                let i++
        done
        i=0
        while [ $i -lt $len ]; do
                NAME="$MBD/${INSERT_DB_NAME[$i]}.sql"
                if [ -e $NAME ]; then
                                $MYSQL -u${INSERT_DB_USER[$i]} -p${INSERT_DB_PASS[$i]} -h${INSERT_DB_HOST[$i]} ${INSERT_DB_NAME[$i]} < $NAME 2>> $LOG_FILE
                                #echo "$MYSQL -u${INSERT_DB_USER[$i]} -p${INSERT_DB_PASS[$i]} -h${INSERT_DB_HOST[$i]} ${INSERT_DB_NAME[$i]} < $NAME"
                                logIt "IMPORT TO ${INSERT_DB_NAME[$i]}"
                else
                        logIt "File $NAME not exist";
                fi
                let i++
        done
}

check_dump()
{
        FILE_TMP_DUMP="$MBD/tmp_dump_${INSERT_DB_NAME[0]}.sql";
        FILE_DIFF_RESS="$MBD/diff_res.diff"
        tmp_tables=`build_tables ${INSERT_DB_PREFIX[0]}`
        ($MYSQLDUMP -u ${INSERT_DB_USER[0]} -h ${INSERT_DB_HOST[0]} -p${INSERT_DB_PASS[0]} ${INSERT_DB_NAME[0]} $tmp_tables 2>>$LOG_FILE) > $FILE_TMP_DUMP
        DIFF="$(which diff)"
        $DIFF $FILE $FILE_TMP_DUMP > FILE_DIFF_RESS
        [ -s "$SMB/diff_res.diff" ];
        SUCCESS=$?
        eval $RM -f $FILE_TMP_DUMP $FILE_DIFF_RESS
        return $SUCCESS
}

if check_dump; then
        input_to_mysql
else
        logIt "No need to dump"
fi
```

so run like dump.sh -c config -l log.file

Where config like this:

```
MyHOST="master_host"
MyUSER="master_user"
MyPASS="master_password"
DB_NAME="master_db_name"
DB_PREFIX="master_db_prefix_" # leave empty if you haven't table prefix

TABLES="table1 table2 table3" // list of tables - leave empty for all tables


###############################
INSERT_DB_NAME=(slave_dbname1 slave_dbname2)
INSERT_DB_HOST=(slave_host1 slave_host2)
INSERT_DB_USER=(slave_user1 slave_user2)
INSERT_DB_PASS=(slave_pass1 slave_pass2)
INSERT_DB_PREFIX=(slave_db_prefix1 slave_db_prefix1) //
```

I putted it to cron and all works fine for me.
Of course you can do all this manually ...

Answer (score 0):

The word you are looking for, is [Replication](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication-howto.html). It's not real time, but almost.

Comment: Oh I see..   Thanks for the link and Info